# Need to sort results by amount of replies in other table SQL

Tags: php, sql, count

I need to retreive data from 3 tables: `t_users`, `t_forum`, `t_replies`.
The thread, the poster, and the amount of replies to that post.

I have made it work like this but I can't see an option to sort it by the most replies.

```
$_result= $_PDO->query("
   SELECT * FROM t_users, t_forum 
   WHERE t_forum.d_op= t_users.d_user_id
   $_orderBy");

    if ($_result->rowCount() > 0) {

    while($_row = $_result-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $_postid = $_row['d_index'];

      //count amount of replies per post
      $_replycount = $_PDO ->query("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                    FROM t_replies 
                                    WHERE d_reply_id = '$_postid'");

     $_count = $_replycount ->fetchColumn();
     }
     }

    //I have tried queries like this :
       SELECT  t_users.*, t_forum.*, COUNT(d_reply_id)
       FROM t_users,t_forum, t_replies
       WHERE t_forum.d_op= t_users.d_user_id
       AND t_forum.d_index = t_replies.d_reply_id

    //but this only retrieves one row and literally counts the d_reply_id value as the
   value is numeric, thank you for reading.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look something like:

```
SELECT  /*put here field of thread and poster*/, COUNT(d_reply_id)
FROM t_users

join t_forum 
on t_forum.d_op= t_users.d_user_id

left join t_replies
on t_forum.d_index = t_replies.d_reply_id

group by /*put here field of thread and poster*/
order by COUNT(d_reply_id) desc
```

Comment: This nearly did the trick, it retrieved everything that had replies to their post, so I made the second join a left join. Thanks a lot for the reply